# how to set transition property to jquery response element?

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, css, animation

i have a html table with percentage width that contain some text. my ajax function change this content to another text with different length, but the `td` width will re-sizing directly after ajax response. how to apply `css3` transition property to column width for soft and animated column re-sizing?

my css code:

```css
table  tr td{
    color: #00cf00;
    padding: 2%;
    font-family: "Courier New";
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 3;
    transition: width 1s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add all the browser prefixes in order to make it work properly :

```
-webkit-transition: width 1s;
-moz-transition: width 1s;
-ms-transition: width 1s;
-o-transition: width 1s;
transition: width 1s;
```

Comment: Can you tell me which prefix is for which browser? I shall be very thankful to you

Comment: Sure. -webkit is for Chrome & Safari and browsers using the Webkit engine, -moz is for Mozilla Firefox, -ms for Internet Explorer and -o for opera.

Answer (score 0):

You can also animate through jquery. It is quite easy. The following code changes the column size smoothly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("table tr td").animate({width:"100px"},2000);
    $("table tr td").animate({height:'100px'},1000);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div> 
<table >
<tr><td style="background:red; width:200px;height:200px;text-align:center">Ammad</td><td style="text-align:center;background:green; width:200px;height:200px;" >Umair</td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```